# ¿Como puedo enviar el resultado de un button desde una clase CardViewDataAdapter al MainActivity?

Tags: android

Tengo unos botones dentro del Cardview que se muestran dentro de un ReciclerView y cuando pulso en los botones btnMas y btMenos quiero enviar los datos al MainActivity porque allí tengo una función que los manda a una pagina web en php.
Lo que ocurre es que  pasar valores de clase a una activity no se como se hace, de una activity a otra si que se.

Adjunto código.

public class CardViewDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private List<ClaseArticulo> stList;

public Integer suma;
public Integer resta;
public Integer intIdArticulo=0;


public CardViewDataAdapter(List<ClaseArticulo> articulos, int cardview_row) {
    this.stList = articulos;

}

public CardViewDataAdapter() {


}


// Create new views
@Override
public CardViewDataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                         int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.cardview_row, null);

    // create ViewHolder

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);

    return viewHolder;
}



@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder,final int position) {

    final int pos = position;

    viewHolder.tvNombre.setText(stList.get(position).getNombre());

    viewHolder.tvCantidad.setText(stList.get(position).getCantidad());


    //GUARDO LA CANTIDAD EN LA VARIABLE
    final String strCantindad=stList.get(position).getCantidad();

    viewHolder.chkSelected.setChecked(stList.get(position).isCheckArticulo());

    viewHolder.chkSelected.setTag(stList.get(position));

    viewHolder.chkSelected.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
            ClaseArticulo contact = (ClaseArticulo) cb.getTag();

            contact.setCheckArticulo(cb.isChecked());

            stList.get(pos).setCheckArticulo(cb.isChecked());


            /*
                 Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() + " is "
                         + cb.isChecked()+strCantidad2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            */


        }
    });

    viewHolder.btnMas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            intIdArticulo=stList.get(position).getIdArticulo();

            //CONVIERTO LA VARIABLE EN INTEGER PARA PODERLO SUMAR
            suma= Integer.valueOf(strCantindad);

            suma=suma+1;

            //QUIERO ENVIAR LOS DATOS A MainActivity

            //EditarDatos(id_articulo.toString(),suma.toString());

           // Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "cantidad " +suma+"id "+intIdArticulo, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




        }
    });

    viewHolder.btnMenos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Integer resta;

            Integer intIdArticulo=stList.get(position).getIdArticulo();

            //CONVIERTO LA VARIABLE EN INTEGER PARA PODERLO SUMAR
            resta= Integer.valueOf(strCantindad);

            resta=resta-1;

            //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), " " +resta, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //EditarDatos(id_articulo.toString(),resta.toString());


        }
    });


}


// Return the size arraylist
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return stList.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView tvNombre;
    public TextView tvCantidad;
    public CheckBox chkSelected;
    public Button btnMas;
    public Button btnMenos;
    public LinearLayout Lnfila;


    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);

        tvNombre = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.text_nombre);

        tvCantidad = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.text_cantidad);
        chkSelected = (CheckBox) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.articulo_checkBox);
        btnMas = (Button) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.mas);
        btnMenos = (Button) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.menos);
        btnMenos = (Button) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.menos);
        Lnfila= (LinearLayout) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.articulo_card);



    }

}

// method to access in activity after updating selection
public List<ClaseArticulo> getArticulos() {
    return stList;
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Para comunicar un botón de la lista con la Activity, necesitas un callback (interfaz) con el ViewHolder. Traduzco el artículo original: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32720702/how-to-call-a-mainactivity-method-from-viewholder-in-recyclerview-adapter

Primero crea un callback.  Algunos lo declaran en el fichero del Adapter pero te recomiendo hacerlo en uno nuevo:

```
public interface OnItemClicklistener {
    void onClick(Int value);
}
```

Para inicializar el valor del callback puedes hacerlo en el Adapter a través de un setter o por constructor.  Por ejemplo con un setter:

```
private OnItemClicklistener onItemClicklistener;

private void setOnItemClicklistener(OnItemClicklistener onItemClicklistener) {
    this.onItemClicklistener = onItemClicklistener;
}
```

En el ViewHolder pasarás el valor cuando el usuario seleccione un botón:

```
viewHolder.btnMas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            intIdArticulo=stList.get(position).getIdArticulo();

            suma= Integer.valueOf(strCantindad);

            suma=suma+1;

            if (onItemClicklistener != null) {
                onItemClicklistener.onClick(suma);
            }
        }
```

Por último, en tu Activity, sólo tienes que setear el callback:

```
 cardViewDataAdapter.setOnItemClicklistener(new OnItemClicklistener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(Int value) {
               // TODO your logic
         }
  })
```

Si en el futuro empleas Kotlin en lugar de Java, el callback te va a funcionar pero también puedes investigar sobre las Higher Order Functions (lambdas).

Comment: Se te agradece el apoyo pero responder con solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad, checa [answer]; ahora si consideras que el contenido del enlace es útil a la duda eres bienvenido a traducirlo y agregarlo aquí dejando los créditos a su autor

Comment: He realizado los cambios solicitados, gracias!